# Error in using AJAX in mobile browser when method is POST

Tags: jquery, ajax, mobile-website

I have a mobile website made purely in HTML-5 Javascript and CSS.This website works fine in desktop browser but in mobile browser the AJAX POST works fine at most of the places but at some places it doesnot ...the readystate doesnot get changed it remain 0 but at those places if I change method to GET it works.I tried using default android browser,Dolphin but the same problem persists.Kindly Help me in this regard!

PS-For posting data in AJAX request I am using formdata.
I have found that the real problem is in FormData only the FormData works sometimes and it doesnot sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Every browser handles javascript slightly diffrently, on mobiles this can be very diffrent from the desktop. I recomend using a library like [jquery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) to handle the quirks for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply man but I have edited this question just have a look at it.

Comment: If you use jquery mobile to to the actual post it should work.